# NGINX Location Blocks for PHP subpaths

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to filter a path to specifically do the following (in this order I think):

1. Allow all traffic from everywhere in the world to the path /PROD/index.php?/report (and anything after /report like the examples below) and block traffic to anywhere else

   - ALLOW: /PROD/index.php?/report
   - ALLOW: /PROD/index.php?/report/
   - ALLOW: /PROD/index.php?/report/werwf
   - DENY: /PROD/index.php?/{anything else}
2. Allow all traffic from any IP address in the range we own (denoted by x.x.x.x/16)

The current NGINX config I have is:

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fsmunkireport.stockton.edu.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/fsmunkireport.stockton.edu.key;
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    location = / {
      return 301 https://fqdn/PROD/index.php?;
    }

    location ~ ^\/PROD\/index.php\?\/report(.*) {
      allow all;
      index index.php;
      autoindex on;
      location ~* \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /secure/PPRD/$fastcgi_script_name;
          include fastcgi_params;
          include fastcgi.conf;
      }
    }

    location /PROD {
      allow x.x.x.x/16;
      deny all;
      index index.php;
      autoindex on;
      location ~* \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /secure/PPRD/$fastcgi_script_name;
          include fastcgi_params;
          include fastcgi.conf;
      }
    }
}
```

The issue I am running into is filtering through that php subpath. Since it isn't a literal directory I think I am just confusing myself. Basically at this point all traffic is allowed via NGINX which isn't the desired behavior.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should set a `break;` in the middle location block, or the third one overrides it.

Comment: I added the break at the end of the regex location block but it still isn't functioning as expected..

Comment: `location` statements are matched to a normalized URI which does not include the `?` and query string. Your second `location` block will never match anything. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) for details.

Comment: But shouldn't a regex statement match the case first considering the ? and /'s are escaped properly?
I am going to read through that page now though..
Maybe a location block isn't the proper way to approach this, if that is so, any ideas what might be?